# Google Services Conflict Error

Tags: java, android, gradle

Am trying to build my project but suddenly started getting this frustrating error on my log cat about google services version conflict. I have tried all the possible solutions online to fix things yet its not working. I have updated my **google-services.json** file, even upgraded my google-servies dependencies, cleaned and rebuild my project even invalidated caches yet still getting same error.

**Build.gradle(app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(path: ':Material-Color-Picker-master')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Build.gradle (Project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Error**

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.
```

Comment: show error log.

Comment: remove apply plugin `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')`

Comment: review my code please

Comment: remove `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` above `compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')`

Comment: do i need to remove that youtube library? am actually using its api in the app

Comment: Solved this yet?

Comment: yes. check my solution above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this problem by removing this line from my **build.gradle(project)** module.

```
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Error**

```
Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.
```

**Reason**

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
```

Remove **`YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar`** from your local lib folder and add

```
 compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev187-1.23.0'
```

with

```
 repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

**Finally**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(path: ':Material-Color-Picker-master')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev187-1.23.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.